# Error when running cucumberjs ft. selenium, phantomjs, webdriverio

Tags: node.js, selenium, phantomjs, cucumberjs, webdriver-io

I already installed phantomjs globally `npm install -g phantomjs`

Started selenium with `java -jar selenium-standalone-2.52.0.jar`

Configure the `World` object for cucumberjs properly like this:

```
var options = {
    //desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'internet explorer' }, // WORK
    //desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' }, // WORK
    desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'phantomjs' }, // NOT WORK
    waitforTimeout     : 2000,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444
};

this.browser = webdriverio.remote(options);
```

It worked with chrome & IE, but failed for phantomjs.

This is the error I got from Selenium console:

> ERROR - org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed
>   (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\phantomjs" (in directory "."):
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)

`C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\phantomjs` exists.

Do I miss any configuration for phantom / selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I found the reason in this similar [github issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12616).

`C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\phantomjs` only works for Linux system. Looks like the webdriver for phantomjs didn't check for the case of running on window application.

To quick-fix the problem, I remove the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\phantomjs`, so selenium will automatically call phantomjs.bat on the same folder. Everything will work fine.